# Preg_replace for encoding

Tags: php, regex

I am really bad in regex expression,

there is below code i saw in my existing application in php but not really understanding what it is doing.

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<?xml[^>]*)encoding=["\']([^>"\']*)?["\']([^>]*?>)/', '$1encoding="' . $encoding . '"$3', $content);

        return $content;
```

If any expert can share some info that would be really great.

**Update**

Trying to run this but not working is there anything i am missing here..

```
$encoding = 'UTF-32';
$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel></channel>';
echo preg_replace('/(<?xml[^>]*)encoding=["\']([^>"\']*)?["\']([^>]*?>)/', '$1encoding="' . $encoding . '"$3', $content);
```

**update**

It may sound stupid.. but it was working... as it is XML tag so for that i need to do display source in chrome and it will display it...

Thank you everyone.. specially M42

regards,
Mona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will change the encoding present in the file by a new one contained in the variable `$encoding`

Example:

```
 <?xml blah blah encode="XXX" blah blah?>
```

will be changed to (assuming `$encoding='UTF-8';`):

```
 <?xml blah blah encode="UTF-8" blah blah?>
```

`$1` contains: `<xml blah blah`
`$3` contains: `blah blah>`
The result is the concatenation of `$1`, `encode="UTF-8"` and $3.

*Regex explanation:*

```
The regular expression:

(<?xml[^>]*)encoding=["\']([^>"\']*)?["\']([^>]*?>)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?                       '<' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    xml                      'xml'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  encoding=                'encoding='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ["\']                    any character of: '"', '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>"\']*                 any character except: '>', '"', '\'' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ["\']                    any character of: '"', '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*?                   any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you M42..  $encoding=UTF-8, $content= all XML Data but i dont understand what is $1encoding and $3 here do you have any idea... if you could give any example.. thank you in advance.

Comment: th avariable there is no th variable ;)

Comment: trying to execute it looks something wrong.. not working $encoding = 'UTF-32';
$content = '<?xml encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
 echo preg_replace('/(<?xml[^>]*)encoding=["\']([^>"\']*)?["\']([^>]*?>)/', '$1encoding="' . $encoding . '"$3', $content);